# Adding some initial code before Play Framework started

Tags: java, playframework-2.0

I want to perform some configuration options (log4j and ActiveJDBC) in my Play application, but cannot find a way to add custom code on stratup.

Is there any option to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to define class extending `GlobalSettings` in the root package and override one of two methods: `beforeStart`(body executed before any plugin) or `onStart`(body executed after all plugins), depends what you exactly need. See [Docs](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.1.1/JavaGlobal) and [API](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/api/2.1.1/java/play/GlobalSettings.html).

Comment: root package is `app` or project root?